# Are the same microSD cards compatible with the Rasberry Pi Zero?

Tags: sd-card, compatibility, pi-zero

Are all of the microSD, microSDHC, and microSDXC cards on [the list from the Embedded Linux Wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) compatible with the Raspberry Pi Zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hardware/software stack to read the SD card is common between the Pi A/A+/B/B+/Zero.

That being the case any card which is readable/writeable on one of those machines should be readable/writeable on the Pi Zero.

Given that the differences between the Pi2B and the others is fairly minor (in the SD card area) I'd expect any which are readable/writeable on the Pi2 to be readable/writeable on the Pi Zero as well.